# APPLICATION_JSON cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, json, rest

I have a problem producing JSON in my application.

I'm trying a tutorial about [Consuming Java Restful Web Service with AngularJS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F201AN5UEg0).
I've created a dynamic web project as my RESTful server and then added the following libraries:

- asm-3.3.1.jar
- jackson-core-asl-1.9.9.jar
- jackson-jaxrs-1.9.9.jar
- jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.9.jar
- jackson-xc-1.9.9.jar
- jersey-bundle-1.8.jar
- jersey-bundle-1.9.jar
- jersey-client-1.9.jar
- jersey-core-1.9.jar
- jersey-json-1.9.jar
- jersey-media-json-jettison-2.4.jar
- jersey-server-1.9.1.jar
- jersey-servlet-1.12.jar
- jettison-1.3.3.jar
- jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar

Here is the service :

```
package ws;

import java.awt.PageAttributes.MediaType;
import java.util.*;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;

import entities.Prospect;

@Path("prospect")
public class ProspectRestful {

    @GET
    @Path("findall")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Prospect> findAll(){

        List<Prospect> result = new ArrayList<Prospect>();

        result.add(new Prospect(35, "Name 35", "last35"));
        result.add(new Prospect(36, "Name 36", "last36"));


        return result;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> APPLICATION_JSON cannot be resolved or is not a field.

I've seen in another question that jersey-media-json-jettison-2.4.jar should be there so I added it but no sign.

I'm sure I'm not using a Maven project, in the same tutorial they didn't use Maven either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Remove this

```
import java.awt.PageAttributes.MediaType;
```

and add this

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
```

Comment: It worked ! oh i was struggling because of that  ! Thank you so much for your rapid answer !

Comment: @shazin this is not working for me ... I am trying to use APPLICATION_PDF ... I  have also used `import org.springframework.http.MediaType;` but It doesn't work for me

Answer (score 14):

In my case it is not working, so if anyone facing the error then try...

```
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
```

It worked for me...

Comment: Worked for me too. Add this library and call MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE